# Any other sites for exchanging bitcoin for ripple apart from shapeshift and changelly?

Tags: exchanges, ripple, shapeshift.io

I want to buy some ripple using bitcoin, but [shapeshift](https://shapeshift.io/#/coins) sets a minimum for the transaction that is way above the initial deposit of 20 XRP necessary for an unfunded ripple wallet. At the moment of writing this, shapeshift requires a minimum deposit of 0.01451925 BTC, which is 93.43467259 XRP. But I don't want to buy so many XRPs.

Besides, [changelly](https://changelly.com/) doesn't currently support ripple.

Comment: You should use Altcoin Converter from AltTopia.net. It supports small amounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view all exchanges that support converting XRP <-> BTC on coinmarketcap.com . [Here](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/#markets) are all the markets that XRP trades on. Just look for markets that say **XRP/BTC**.

I've successfully exchanged XRP on Bitstamp and Poloniex.

Answer (score 1):

You can get help from a [Coin Exchange Service](https://coinswappy.com/app#/estimate/BTC/XRP/0.04) aggregator like CoinSwappy.

For XRP needs you can see these 3 exchange support the XRP purchase.

[image]

Comment: It seems at the time your were checking the web changelly did support ripple, but I have checked changelly a few times and I still don't see ripple there. It seems they are having some issues with ripple right now.

Comment: Its a volatile market, so it might be case they capacity was overloaded at changelly !